# Селениум не открывает браузер

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

Селениум после выполнения кода не открывает браузер, вообще ничего не происходит. Как исправить, в папке только проект и драйвер

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def get_source_html(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"\Users\Sergey\Desktop\q\chromedriver")

    try:
        driver.get(url=url)
    except Exception as _ex:
        print(_ex)
    finally:
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()

def main():
    get_source_html(url='https://foundation.app/profiles?sortBy=users_sort_total_vol_desc')

if __name__ == '__parse__':
    main()
```

[image]
покапался в питоне  вот че нашел, может кому-то понадобится

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: для скачивания драйвер был только для x32 винды а у меня x64, может в этом дело?

Comment: Вряд ли дело в этом.

Comment: помгите кто нибудь пжслт, (тот кто сверху) ну в коде или нет?

Comment: НАРОООД, я убрал последний if и оставил только main(), и все заработало!!!!!!!!!!!!!))))))  только теперь он закрывается через секунду

Answer (score 0):

Используй webdriver_manager он сам будет скачивать и ставить последний драйвер. Тебе больше не нужно будет с этим заморачиваться. https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager

"НАРОООД, я убрал последний if и оставил только main(), и все заработало!!!!!!!!!!!!!)))))) только теперь он закрывается через секунду" так у тебя ничего и не происходит в коде, он открывает ссылку и закрывается.